# What's the opposite(?) command of "econstructor"

Tags: coq

For example,

```
Lemma ex_1:
exists n, n=1.
Proof.
```

shows one subgoal:

```
exists n : nat, n = 1
```

the econstructor command changes the goal to

```
?n = 1
```

what is the command that can get

```
exists n : nat, n = 1
```

again from "?n = 1"?

or, let's say we proved some sublemma with (exists n, ~) form for this.
How can we "apply" the sublemma?

Answer (score 2):

Théo Winterhalter gave some strategies that work in this case, but in general, `econstructor` isn't invertible in a few senses.

### `econstructor` can take two different proof states to the same end state.

Which is to say, `econstructor` isn't injective on proof states. For example, consider this (rather stupid) situation.

```
Inductive exists': Prop :=
| intro (n: nat): n = 1 -> exists'.

Goal exists'.
Proof.
  econstructor.
```

We end up with the exact same end state, even though the starting goal (before `econstructor`) was different.

### `econstructor` loses information in general.

Even if we know what the original state was, it might not be possible to get back to it. For this example, we'll use `inhabited` from the standard library, but it works just as well for `exists`, since `inhabited A` is equivalent to `exists a: A, True`.

```
Goal forall A: Type, inhabited A -> inhabited A.
Proof.
  intros A H.
  econstructor.
```

Now the proof state is

```
1 subgoal
A : Type
H : inhabited A
______________________________________(1/1)
A
```

and we'd like to use `H` to solve the goal. But this is (in general) impossible. We can't start from the mere statement that an element of type `A` exists and generate an actual term of type `A`. The problem is that since `H` is a `Prop`, we can destruct it (or match on it) if the goal is also a `Prop`. After using `econstructor`, this is no longer the case, so we have to have an explicit witness of type `A`. In your example, it works since we know exactly which element of `nat` satisfies `n = 1`, but in general, we can't know that

The proof assistant [Lean uses](https://github.com/leanprover/lean/blob/cbd2b6686ddb566028f5830490fe55c0b3a9a4cb/library/init/classical.lean#L13) the general statement `forall A, nonempty A -> A` (`nonempty` is the same as Coq's `inhabited`) to power its classical logic library. The same proof of excluded middle works in Coq (assuming functional extensionality and propositional extensionality). So, if we have `forall A: Type, inhabited A -> A`, then the law of excluded middle, and even some strong versions of the axiom of choice, are provable (with the addition of some extensionality axioms).

---

Also note that when you use `econstructor`, any existential variables must eventually be instantiated with values that exist in the *current* context. If you have `H: exists n: nat, n = 1`, you'll have to destruct `H` *before* using `econstructor`.

```
Hypothesis H: exists n: nat, n = 1.

Goal exists n: nat, n = 1.
Proof.
  destruct H as [x H].
  econstructor.
  exact H.
Defined.

Goal exists n: nat, n = 1.
Proof.
  econstructor.
  destruct H as [x H].
  Fail exact H.
Abort.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have hypothesis

```
H : exists n : nat, n = 1
```

you can use

```
destruct H as [n Hn]
```

to get hypotheses

```
n : nat
Hn : n = 1
```

This is how you *use* such an information.

For the other part of the question, I would need to see an example of what you're trying to do. Here you use `econstructor` (it could also be `eexists`) so you get an existential variable `?n` in your context, and it will then be solved by *unification*.
For instance, you then solve `?n = 1` by `reflexivity` which is a proof of `1 = 1`, so Coq knows `?n` must have been `1`.

You can also be more precise and use the `exist` tactic to give the witness directly.

```
exists 1. reflexivity.
```